# How to tag tests in akka's TestKit using scala?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka, actor, scalatest

I want to tag certain tests in order to (not) run them in certain scenarios. (E.g. `slow` that should only run during build, yet not while developing.)

In Scala using ScalaTest's FlatSpec I know I can use `taggedAs` and scalatest's `Tag`.

Yet I don't know how to achieve the same thing within an actor test. I have have TestCase that extends `TestKit` and there seems to be no taggedAs functionality in there as FlatSpec provides.

I want to be able to filter in/out the tests via

```
sbt "testOnly -- -l myTag" # runs all except the tagged tests
sbt "testOnly -- -n myTag" # only runs the tagged tests
```

How can I achive that with akka's test framework?

Comment: For me there is nothing specific to Akka TestKit, but to the test framework used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka's `TestKit` assumes the use of a testing framework. From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/testing.html#different-testing-frameworks):

> Akka’s own test suite is written using [**ScalaTest**](http://www.scalatest.org/), which also shines through in documentation examples. However, the TestKit and its facilities do not depend on that framework, you can essentially use whichever suits your development style best.

In other words, one uses `TestKit` in conjunction with a framework like ScalaTest. Mix in `TestKit` and whatever ScalaTest traits you want to use (e.g., `FlatSpec`) into your test, and you can use `taggedAs`.

For example, consider one of Akka's internal tests, [`SupervisorHierarchySpec`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.8/akka-actor-tests/src/test/scala/akka/actor/SupervisorHierarchySpec.scala), that uses `TestKit` with ScalaTest tagging:

```
class SupervisorHierarchySpec extends AkkaSpec(SupervisorHierarchySpec.config) with DefaultTimeout with ImplicitSender {
  ...
  "A Supervisor Hierarchy" must {

    "restart manager and workers in AllForOne" taggedAs LongRunningTest in {
       ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

This test extends [`AkkaSpec`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.8/akka-testkit/src/test/scala/akka/testkit/AkkaSpec.scala), which is an abstract class that mixes in both `TestKit` and ScalaTest traits:

```
abstract class AkkaSpec(_system: ActorSystem)
  extends TestKit(_system) with WordSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll with WatchedByCoroner
  with ConversionCheckedTripleEquals with ScalaFutures {
  ...
}
```

And [`LongRunningTest`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.8/akka-testkit/src/test/scala/akka/testkit/TestTags.scala#L9) is a ScalaTest tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new annotation in a **java** file like this:

```
package org.acme;

import org.scalatest.TagAnnotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@TagAnnotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface IntegrationTest { }
```

And then you can tag your suite like this:

```
@IntegrationTest
class AcmeTest extends ... {
}
```

And finally you can exclude it by passing it via `-l org.acme.IntegrationTest`  (Note the FQCN)